# What is the difference between assigning null and not assigning null?

Tags: java, memory, null, variable-assignment

What is the difference between(assigning `null` and not assigning `null`) 
in java in terms of memory and all?

```
String str;    
String str = null;
```

Comment: @TheLostMind that's true only for local variable. Class members are automatically initialised with null values

Comment: @blackbelt - Didn't look like class/instance level declarations... So thought I would just give the "local" or "method" level scope answer..  :)

Comment: Hmm I don't thing this question should downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `String str;` is a local variable (not a class member), it is not initialized. Compiling will fail with the error that `str` not initialized.

If `str` is an instance or static member of a class, its default value is `null` so there is no difference.

> ... in terms of memory and all?

There is no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Inside a method if the variable is a local variable :
```

In the first case the compiler will throw error saying that str is not initialized (during compilation)... in the second, it wont... Other than that, no difference whatsoever...

```
2. If str is at class level :
```

It makes no difference (thanks to @Ruchira for this.. )

Answer (score 0):

If it's a class variable, there's no difference. If it's a local/method variable, you will get compile-time error if you do only `String str;` and if you then try to use `str` later (because it is not initialized).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **String str;** *inside a method* then we'll get a compilation error when you try to use **str** *without initializing it*. But when you're declaring **str** *as a instance variable*, even tough if you don't initialize it the ***default constructor will initialize the instance variable*** *str* to **null** since str is of type String which is a **non-primitive** data type in java.